# Insert Total value of order, or calculate every time?

Tags: php, database, database-design, e-commerce

I'm building a simple e-commerce website with order confirmation and creation.

Should I calculate the total order value, and insert it into the database, or should I calculate it every time I read or do something with the order?

Comment: It depends on database layout anyway. I'd say both solutions are good. I don't think there is a best practice for that.

Comment: @Nemoden Ok... I like to ask those things here, because sometimes there is a problem that i don't know... Like 'not to link address table with order table'... (because user can edit address)... Thanks anyway =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practices in database land means normalised data, and storing values that can be calculated violates that.

You should generally *never* store things that you can calculate unless you're *absolutely* certain that there won't be a discrepancy between the two values.

> For example, what do you think should happen if your order consists of two $100 items but the order is set to $150?

Sometimes, there are justifications (usually performance related) to storing values that can be otherwise calculated but the performance gains have to be both *significant* and *necessary,* and the possibility of inconsistency either removed or planned for.

You can remove the possibility with things like triggers or materialised views, and you can plan for them by changing business logic to detect and fix problems, or by other means.

But usually, the performance gains aren't worth the extra effort of mitigating the potential problems. After all, how many orders do you see with *millions* of individual items on them?

Other than the US DoD, of course, where the Bill Of Materials for an aircraft carrier lists every single nut and bolt used to build it :-)

Answer (score 4):

In your transactional database (ie the main, live one) you should not store the calculated value. Summing a dozen rows is nothing.

However, in your analytic database (aka business intelligence db-, data warehouse) you should definitely store the calculated total.

Answer (score 1):

As a good practice, you should not store values that can be derived from existing columns in the table.

There are many reasons not to do this such as

1. If you want to update any of the underlying columns , then you have to update the derived column as well.
2. size of the table will be increased

etc.. etc..