# How to create virtual field with 'complex' math function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, e-commerce

I'm creating an simple e-commerce website, and as I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000269/insert-total-value-of-order-or-calculate-every-time) if i should or shouldn't insert the total of the order in the database... The general answer was 'NO', so i accepted that.

But now, i'm doing some stuffs, and i remembered that Mysql is not a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE guy, and maybe, he could perform the `math` to calculate the order total...

I have actualy 2 tables:

- Orders
- Products (that has quantity, and price values)

Is there a way, of creating an virtualfield (in CakePHP), that automaticaly calculates the total value of the order with those two values?

Thanks

Comment: MySQl has al lot of math functions. You could use SUM

Comment: @John But is there something `already done` like this, in Cake? I hate to discovery things like this latter... I haven't found anything (maybe i don't know the key word to search) ^^

Comment: Create a join to products table and create a virtual with `SUM(Product.quantiy * Product.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not making 2 tables first (x_orders_products) with id,order_id , product_id, quantity, date and the other one(orders) with id, user_id .
On insert in orders get the last inserted id ant then insert in x_orders_products then based on these data generate a view to calculate the order.